# Julia: How to deal with ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package?

Tags: julia

When I install packages, I sometimes encounter this error. What is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: There's a useful thread on this exact topic on Julia Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/a-guide-how-to-handle-error-unsatisfiable-requirements-detected/43406

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to use the `]activate` command.

Just create a new directory somewhere, e.g. c:/a_new_directory then activate

`]activate c:/a_new_directory`

Once activated, you can install whatever packages you need since it's a fresh environment.

Every time you want to use the same set of packages together, just `activate` that directory.

Try not to install everything using `add` try to do activate before `add`.

Comment: Wow. Julia has made my coding life a lot easier, but I never though it would also make me stop loathing virtual environments! XD

Comment: Here's a good intro on `]activate` and project environments: https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/10/julia-project-environments.html. Also, from the official docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/